# Should I use "co-created with" or "co-created by" for correct attribution of content?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In my PhD thesis, I wish to describe a software toolbox that I created in equal parts along with 2 other people (say Alice and Bob).

Should I say

> "This software toolbox was **co-created with** Alice and Bob?" or "This software toolbox was **co-created by** Alice and Bob?"

Since it is my Phd thesis, it is implicit that I am a creator. In fact, the university requires a covering statement that everything I say in the thesis is entirely my contribution, unless explicitly stated otherwise, properly acknowledged and appropriately referenced.

If it matters, this is in England, and although I am from India, I am not considered a native speaker by my institution.

Comment: Or along with  ?

Comment: What do other people put in theses? [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=co-created+with%2Cco-created+by&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cco%20-%20created%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cco%20-%20created%20by%3B%2Cc0) isn't helping much.

Comment: @Shmuel, you meant "created along with", right?

Comment: You're asking your audience / readership to infer the unspoken but implicit highlighted element *was co-created **by myself along with** Alice and Bob*. If you only preserve the first preposition *(**by**)*, that's not really a credible interpretation. If you're not going to explicitly mention yourself, the only way you could reasonably expect to be understood would be to use ***with*** (which *forces* the audience to recognise that there must be someone else involved besides Alice and Bob).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  This is a PhD thesis, which is primarily an individuals own work, that of the author (A Phd thesis cannot be co-authored). However, these days, we live in a cross-disciplinary collaborative environment wherein better progress can be achieved by leveraging the expertise of another one for a specific sub-task.  That is fine, as long as in the document that other contributor is properly acknowledged specifically identifying to what sub-task the other person contributed to.

Comment: I understand perfectly well that your target audience should be aware that ***you*** must be the primary author of your own thesis. But since you're writing in *English*, you can't expect them to override their natural expectations of what *[co-]created by A and B* means (i.e. - A & B collectively created it, ***not with anyone else***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Understood. Thank you for clarifying. So _created together with_ sounds ok, like the answer below says

Comment: I'd normally talk about something like a "software toolbox" being ***developed*** rather than ***created***. And since presumably it would never have existed at all if you hadn't been involved (regardless of whether you personally did more or less of the development work than A or B, separately or collectively), for your context I'd prefer *...was developed with the assistance of A & B*. But your version is obviously both comprehensible and acceptable, as would be @Tim's suggested alternatives. I really think "co-created" is a bit "stuffy" for your context though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Created by Alice and Bob" means that only those two people were involved: "Co-created by Alice and Bob" I would expect to mean the same since *co-* means only that more than one person was involved, which the reader can tell from the word *and*.  If you use either, you can expect a question about whether you actually played any part in the creation of this software.

"Created with..." or (better) "created together with..." would be the way to indicate that this was a three-person job.

Comment: Thank you for the accept, but it is usual to wait a day or two, in case somebody provides a better answer.

Comment: Or even "_in conjunction with..._". @OP: You say "_it is implicit that I am a creator_" but that isn't necessarily so. It would be quite normal for other people to have created a toolbox that you only use.

Comment: @TripeHound Not for a Phd thesis at a degree granting university

Answer (score 2):

Both of these suggest that you were not included. The *co-* could just mean Alice and Bob did it together. So the *co-* serves no useful purpose here and should be removed unless you wish to emphasise that it was a co-production.

Say

> I created it with Alice and Bob

or

> Alice and Bob created it with me

or

> It was created by Alice, Bob and myself.

This last is, in my opinion, the most elegant and does not prioritize anyone.

To meet the requirements, you may wish to emphasise that it was a co-creation so you can add *co-* to any of these.

Comment: +1 , Using this will not be ambiguous about the involvement of OP.

Comment: +1 for getting rid of the passive voice, which is a main source of the trouble.

Comment: I disagree: I would definitely understand “co-created with X and Y” to mean the authors were X, Y, and the current speaker/writer.